# I cannot get the response of s3 bucket in an observable angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular2-observables

I'm trying to get the data of a bucket in s3 but it did not work.
i want to do have the data as a return value in getFiles(Observables for example)
Do you hava an idea please?

```js
getFiles() {
  const avro = require("avsc");
  const params = {
    Bucket: this.BUCKET,
    Key: this.key
  };

  this.test = this.getS3Bucket().getObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("There was an error : " + err);
      return;
    }
    return data;
  });

  return this.test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
   var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
   let spacesEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(process.env.S3_BUCKET_ENDPOINT);
   var credentials = {
    endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
    accessKeyId:process.env.S3_BUCKET_KEY ,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_BUCKET_SECRET,
    region: process.env.S3_BUCKET_REGION
  };
   var s3 = new AWS.S3(credentials);
   var params = { Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME, Key: File_name };
   getObject(params , function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      res.send(data);
    }
  });
```